# Showing images from center radiating outwards, rather than top left in rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Now sure how to word this, that's probably why my searches didn't give me anything.

Basically, normally if you put out a bunch of images:

```
<img src="whatever.jpg"><img src="whatever2.jpg"><img src="whatever3.jpg">
```

The images will come up from the top left then wrap to the next row when it gets to the end of the screen.

What should I do as to have the images start in the center, with new images spreading out from the center, rather than in rows? I'm thinking there would be some sort of maths involved to do this, and my maths is terrible. I think the last time I tried this a few months ago, I ended up just making a spiral rather than the example image below (which is what I'm trying to achieve).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUU9C.jpg]

Later on down the track after getting this working, I'm hoping to have it scrollable, as to create an "infinite" lot of pictures that would keep "growing". So I'm thinking this would be using a canvas (html5)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
text-align: center;
```

to the wrapper element. Since images are (by default) inline elements, they will be placed to the center.

You may also need `white-space: nowrap` to avoid breaking rows if they aren't wide enough.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLHsv/)

Comment: This still does the same as default, just horizontally centered.
I'm looking for, as more images are added they come out around the first image, outwards like in the example image.

`for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++){ echo "<img src='someimg$i.jpg'>"; }`

Something like that, but the images are outputted as the example image